# positive definite on 1st quadrant

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

A positive definite symmetric square $n$-matrix is $A$ is characterized by $z^TAz>0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$. One can verify that $A>0$ by checking that all eigenvalues are positive.

Is there a name and/or characterization for a matrix which only satisfies $z^TAz>0$ for $z$ in a quadrant or convex hull e.g. $z\in \mathbb{R}^n_+ $?

Answer (score 0):

The Term that you are looking for is copositivity.